# Slick.js loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to tweak a Slick.js slider, but there is issue while start and while loop end. I know it all can be achieved by tweaking CSS and I've already tried a few variants but no luck. For instance, I've added `margin-left:45px;` and `margin-right:45px` here:

```css
    .slick-center {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
        transform: scale(1.25);
        margin-left: 45px;
        margin-right: 45px;
    }
```

To achieve the result I need it looks perfect, but it's not working as expected.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Slick Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            html,
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
    
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
    
            .slider {
                width: 90%;
                margin: 0px auto;
    
            }
    
            .slick-slide {
                margin: 0px 2px;
            }
    
            .slick-slide img {
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
    
            .slick-prev,
            .slick-next {
                z-index: 10;
                top: 100px;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
    
            .slick-prev {
                left: 10px;
            }
    
            .slick-next {
                right: 10px;
            }
    
    
            .slick-slide {
                transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
                opacity: .2;
            }
    
            .slick-active {
                opacity: .5;
            }
    
            .slick-current {
                opacity: 1;
    
            }
    
            .slick-center {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
                -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
                transform: scale(1.25);
                margin-left: 45px;
                margin-right: 45px;
            }
    
            .slick-list {
                padding: 45px 60px !important;
                margin-left: 30px !important;
            }
    
            .slick-track {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-wrap: nowrap;
                justify-content: center;
            }
    
            .slick span {
                display: block;
                background: #3498db;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 36px;
                height: 100px;
                line-height: 100px;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                /* border: solid 1px rgb(145, 195, 0); */
                /* make the non-centered slides partially transparent */
                opacity: .5;
            }
    
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body style="background-color: firebrick">
    
        <section class="center slider">
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=2">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=3">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=4">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=5">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/470x250?text=6">
            </div>
        </section>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('ready', function() {
                $(".center").slick({
                    dots: false,
                    infinite: true,
                    centerMode: true,
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 3
                });
            });
    
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having and the result you're hoping for?

Comment: It has scroll issue. There are 6 tiles and if you begin to scroll everything seems ok untill you'll pass 6-th tile. If you remove margin-left: 45px; and margin-right: 45px; from CSS everything will work but the design will be lost.